# I am unable to cancel an ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I am new to web programming. I have a pretty standard page that accepts contact information and I am trying to add validation controls to it. When the user clicks the cancel button nothing is saved so I just want to unload the page and go back to the previous page. My problem is, even the the cancel button has `CausesValidation="false` the validation events are still firing and a post back does not occur. I am using Visual Studio 2012 and C#. I've created a test page to reduce the code I'm working with to the minimum required code to demonstrate the issue. I have tried the javascript disableValidation() function with both Page_Validation = false; and the loop to disable the individual validation controls without success. When I check Page_Validation it is false, and the loop throws the exception **Page_Validators is undefined**.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestMe.aspx.cs" Inherits="ElmoWeb.TestMe" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Simple Little Test Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="uxEmail" runat="server" placeHolder="email address" type="email" AutoCompleteType="Email"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="uxEmailValidator" runat="server"
                ControlToValidate="uxEmail"
                ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z][\w\._%+-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$"
                ErrorMessage="The email address is invalid"
                EnableClientScript="false" ValidationGroup="testing"
                Display="Static"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CausesValidation="true" UseSubmitBehavior="true" ValidationGroup="testing" />
            <asp:Button ID="Cancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="false" UseSubmitBehavior="true" ValidationGroup="FakeValidationGroup" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" DisplayMode="List" HeaderText="You must correct the following errors." ValidationGroup="testing" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Currently the code behind just writes a message to the output window so I can see if the post back occurred.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("TextMe.aspx Page_Load event, sender = " + sender.ToString() + ", EventArgs = " + e.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your code behind?

Comment: Try removing UseSubmitBehavior="true" on cancel button or make it false. You can also redirect the page on clientclick event for cancel button.

Comment: Setting `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` worked. I though I had to have that to have the post back so I could check the record back in and cancel the update.

Comment: glad that it could help !

Comment: As a side note, UseSubmitBehavior defaults to true, so you don't have to specify it explicitly. I would try just removing UseSubmitBehavior from both buttons, and see if it works. [MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior.aspx)

Comment: @jac All ASP.NET Button controls (ImageButton, LinkButton, Button) will automatically cause a PostBack when you set them to handle an event (like Click).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The natural way of solving issues where two or more submit buttons should behave in a different way is to use validation groups.

A validation group is set with the ValidationGroup attribute on both a submit button and a group of validators. The same value binds a button and validators and only validators with the same value of the attribute fire when the button is clicked.

In your case, setting the ValidationGroup on the accept button and your validators to "Accept" and leaving the default (empty) value on the cancel button would solve your issue. This is much simpler than any of the workarounds you tried.

Comment: I tried this in the above example setting ValidationGroup in both the RegularExpressionValidator and the asp "Submit" button to "testing", and removing the UseSubmitBehavior attribute from the "Cancel" button. The validation control displayed the error message and the code behind Page_Load event was not fired.

Comment: Try to specify the same validationGroup on the ValidationSummary. Also, to make sure, set the ValidationGroup on the Cancel button to yet another nonempty string. This just got to work.

Comment: Sorry, I got the same result. I have updated my code sample with your solution so you can see if I still have something wrong, but so far setting UseSubmitBehavior = "false" is the only thing that works.

Comment: This is because your input has the "type=email". The browser doesn't let it submit to the server. Either remove the attribute or accept the fact that it is validated client-side.